# Tô querendo que o meu def imprimir(): ... receba o meu def mais_alto(): e o meu def mais_baixo(): e imprima os resultados

Tags: python-3.x

```
lista_aluno = []
lista_tamanho =[]


def nome_altura():      
    for i in range(0,10):
        aluno = str(input('Digite o nome do aluno:\n'))
        lista_aluno.append(aluno)

        tamanho = int(input('Digite a altura:\n')) 
        lista_tamanho.append(tamanho)

        return lista_aluno, lista_tamanho

def mais_alto():  
    nome_maior_aluno = lista_aluno[0]   
    maior_aluno = lista_tamanho[0]    
    for i in lista_tamanho:
        if i > maior_aluno:
            maior_aluno = lista_tamanho[i]
            nome_maior_aluno = lista_aluno[i]
            return nome_maior_aluno,maior_aluno

def mais_baixo(): 

    nome_menor_aluno = lista_aluno[0]  
    menor_aluno = lista_tamanho[0]  
    for c in lista_tamanho:
        if c > menor_aluno:
            menor_aluno = lista_tamanho[c]
            nome_menor_aluno = lista_aluno[c]
            return nome_menor_aluno,menor_aluno

def imprimir(): #Aqui quero imprimir os valores do def mais_alto(): e o do def mai_baixo():
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer a chamada aos respectivos métodos diretamente. Foi necessário também fazer algumas pequenas alterações no seu código, veja se ajuda:

```
lista_aluno = []
lista_tamanho =[]

def nome_altura():      
    for i in range(0,10):
        aluno = str(input('Digite o nome do aluno:\n'))
        lista_aluno.append(aluno)

        tamanho = int(input('Digite a altura:\n')) 
        lista_tamanho.append(tamanho)

    return lista_aluno, lista_tamanho

def mais_alto():  
    index = 0 # Identifica a posicao do registro no array

    nome_maior_aluno = lista_aluno[index]   
    maior_aluno = lista_tamanho[index] 

    for i in lista_tamanho: # i Possui o tamanho do aluno e nao a posicao do registro no array
        if i > maior_aluno: # Identificar a maior altura
            maior_aluno = lista_tamanho[index]
            nome_maior_aluno = lista_aluno[index]
        index += 1 # Segue para o registro na proxima posicao

    return nome_maior_aluno,maior_aluno

def mais_baixo(): 
    index = 0 # Identifica a posicao do registro no array

    nome_menor_aluno = lista_aluno[index]  
    menor_aluno = lista_tamanho[index]  

    for c in lista_tamanho: # c Possui o tamanho do aluno e nao a posicao do registro no array
        if c < menor_aluno: # Identificar a menor altura
            menor_aluno = lista_tamanho[index]
            nome_menor_aluno = lista_aluno[index]
        index += 1 # Segue para o registro na proxima posicao

    return nome_menor_aluno,menor_aluno

def imprimir():
    print('Valor mais alto = {0} :: valor mais baixo = {1}'.format(mais_alto(), mais_baixo()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nome_altura()
    imprimir()
```

Adicionei o trecho **__main__** para realizar a chamada.